# Apply host attributes in Angular template

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript

I have a dead simple Angular 4 component that wraps an `input`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-textbox',
  template: '<input type="text" class="some-class">'
})
export class MyTextBoxComponent {
}
```

The aim is obviously to expand this, but what I don't want to do is duplicate every attribute and event from `input` onto `my-textbox`.

Suppose the user wants to specify a change event and a place holder:

```
<my-textbox placeholder="Nice text" (click)="doSomething($event);"></my-textbox>
```

Is there a way to automatically apply `placeholder` and `(click)` to the input, or do I need to create `@Input` and `@Output` wrappers for each and every attribute or event I want to permit?

**Edit**
There is another reason to want to do this, other than attributes and events: Directives. If I write a component that extends an existing component (like `input`), then I loose the ability use any of the directives written for that component. So for example, I will need to re-implement `ngModel` and all the directives for model-driven forms for every wrapped component. But since I don't know which useful directives may be developed in future, this is going to be a recurring problem.

Comment: How does `doSomething` function look like?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Make it an empty function if you want. The point is that I want whatever is specified in `(click)` to be placed on the `input` tag, not the wrapping `my-textbox` tag.

Comment: Use `host` or `@HostBinding/@HostListener`

Comment: Okay, I'll go look for `HostBinding`/`HostListener`. What is `host`? Something I can use in the HTML, or are you referring to the CSS `:host` selector?

Comment: You can declare event https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.2/packages/core/test/linker/integration_spec.ts#L935 or property https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.2/packages/core/test/linker/integration_spec.ts#L904 It's the same as if you would use `@HostListener` or `@HostBinding`

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but the point was that I was looking for a way to apply these attributes and events automatically - it's a lot of boilerplate and just leaves room for errors when you need to wrap each individually.

Comment: Actually, having read up on `HostListener`/`HostBinding`, I'm pretty sure that's the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Create directive that will apply this to all your elements.

Comment: @yurzui It has taken a few months, but I'm now convinced doing these kinds of things in a directive is probably the way to go (even though it makes enforcement throughout the codebase difficult). If you add this as an answer and expand a little, I'll accept it.